# Angular DataTable - Custom Pagination & Info

Tags: jquery, angularjs, pagination, datatables, angular-datatables

I am new to Angular JS. I am trying to implement datatables.
I am referring the link below.

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/

Now i need to implement some custom changes to the datatable configurations.

Eg.

1. Pagination options i need to be in the format provided in the below image.
   [image: Pagination Format]
2. Pagination Info needs to be like below.

[image]

Looking forward to responses.

Please help if anyone has faced issues similar to this.

~~Suriya

Comment: Please show how exactly you want to change the pagination layout and what you mean by the pagination info. It is not a big deal to change, but really hard to guess for example which icons you are referring to and how "Vanilla..." is supposed to be part of the info.

Comment: @davidkonrad, "Vanilla.." is the input i get from user before fetching table.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the **page info** problem. Please see the code below.

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full')
                     .withDisplayLength(10)
                     .withOption('bFilter', false)
                     .withDOM('<"top pull-left itemtableInfo"i>rt<"bottom"p>')
                     .withLanguage({
                          "sInfo": '<div><span class="searchDetail">Displaying _TOTAL_ results for <b>\"'+$rootScope.searchValue+'\"</b> </span><span class="searchCount pull-right">Showing _START_ to _END_ <a>Show All</a></span>',
                           "processing": "Processing...",
                           "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
                           "paginate": {
                                "first": '<i class="fa fa-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                "last": '<i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                "next": "Next",
                                "previous": "Previous"
                            }
                     });
```

But still couldn't resolve the pagination button customization. I am closing this question as i have posted another question for page control issue. .

**Link :**

[Angular datatable - get current page & Total page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161117/angular-datatable-get-current-page-total-page)

If anyone have better solution for both the issues, please provide me with your suggestions :):)

Answer (score -1):

If you need pagination in AngularJS check this,

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination

Comment: OP does not need pagination, there is a lot of built in pagination styles in dataTables, he want to change the default pagination to something else.